# What does "RelaunchUsingCreateProcess::CreateProcess failed" mean when launching "portable" exectuable?

Tags: windows, runtime-error, portability, portable-executable, portable-applications

I tried searching, but found nothing really helpful. Is there any runtime library missing on my system? Or not up-to-date?

Comment: We need much more information. I can't find anything describing what "RelaunchUsingCreateProcess" is. Also, we need some source code. Also, be sure you are getting all the error messages and such.

Comment: That's about all I have. This is the error message dialog that pops up when I try to launch an executable. I do not have access to the source code, nor do I know the technologies it was created with. I suspect it's converted/packed using VMWare or another alternative to make it "portable".

Comment: Off-topic here, since it isn't your program that is failing.  Try Super User.  Make sure you provide details of the buggy application, preferably including a link to the vendor's web site.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.